# Electron-electron scattering into muon-muon state

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, quantum-electrodynamics

It is common in QED that electron positron pair can scatter into different lepton family such as muon and antimuon pair. Is it possible that two energetic electrons can scatter into two muons ? I have not been able to find any sources treating such a reaction. And I don't see any reason, such as a selection rule, that would prohibit such reaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reaction $$e^-+e^-\to \mu^-+\mu^-$$ is prohibited since it doesn't conserve [lepton number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lepton_number). Every family of leptons has a specific lepton number $L_e, L_\mu$ and $L_\tau$. Leptons carry positive lepton number and anti-leptons carry negative lepton number. In the reaction you gave there's $2L_e$ on the left hand side and $2L_\mu$ on the right hand side, and so it's not conserved.

A scattering like $$e^++e^-\to \mu^++\mu^-$$ is not forbidden since on the LHS you have zero lepton number and on the RHS you have zero as well.

Comment: Now I see why I couldnt find any source :] Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No, $ee\to \mu\mu$ is not likely. For charged leptons there is an approximately conserved [lepton family number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lepton_number#Lepton_flavor_conservation).

It is not strictly conserved, since neutrino mixing may induce violations in it, but it is freakishly *small*, with a [BR bound](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.110.201801) for $\mu\to e\gamma$ of less than 13 orders of magnitude.